# Where is the "willing to relocate" option in my job match preferences?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

[image: Screenshot of Job match preferences page]

I couldn't find the **"willing to relocate"** option in my profile. Is it gone?

Comment: Never mind "willing"...where's the _"please! get me outta here"_ switch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right below, in the *match preferences* secion, you can indicate cities, regions, or entire countries you're willing to relocate to:

[image]

Comment: I was actually looking for that https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqUW3.png option.

Comment: It's no longer a separate option. Adding locations to the list above implies that you're willing to relocate to these places.

Comment: Wow… It is *not at all* discoverable that you can add entire countries. The text hint very clearly says "City, State, Country", which makes "Mountain View, CA, United States" an obvious candidate for entry, but not "United States" or "Norway". Maybe should add an "or" in there somewhere? I've always left this section blank because I don't want to indicate to employers that I want to work in any particular city—I'd be willing to relocate anywhere in my country. Little did I know all this time that entering "United States" was an option...

Comment: Great feedback, thanks! I'll make sure it will be heard.

Comment: The fact that this option can now only be enabled by entering multiple locations is silly. I'm willing to move anywhere given the right situation - why isn't it a separate functionality?

Comment: ZachSaucier has a valid point. This was possible with the previous check box option as seen in @MD.JahidulIslam' comment. There must be some reason why they changed it :(

Comment: Thank you, this was indeed not discoverable.  I will try adding “Earth” or perhaps “Sector 2815” and “First or Second Galaxy” and see how that works out.   [Later:  Badly.]

Answer (score -2):

For those who didn't find the answer yet, I just found a loophole in the site, nothing of that much of a discovery though, it's just basic html....

Follow these steps:

1. Open the Developer tools of the browser while on the you are on the profile page
2. Type the location you want, it could be any string(in my case I wrote down 'Anywhere'), and then change the enabled attribute of the button node from the Elements in the Developer tools.
3. The button would get enabled, just click it and there you have it.